# Program that works on Codepen.io couldn't run on Visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I completed a mini connect-4 game based on the Tic-tac-toe tutorial on Reactjs official website
Code:https://codepen.io/bunansia/pen/KKXXKje?editors=1010
I copied the html,css plus JS file and tried to run on VCS but failed
I have installed node.js, @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react have been installed, and this is how my package.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "react-connect4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src/index.js --out-file public/scripts/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.16.5"
  },
  "description": "",
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
      {
        "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
        "runtime": "automatic", // defaults to classic
        "importSource": "custom-jsx-library" // defaults to react
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have also created .babelrc file instructing where to find the preset

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Have tried multiple ways like converting original JS file to babel version

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src/index.js --out-file public/scripts/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

And I put them in the folder named "public", while js && css files are in the folder named "script"
But when I run it on live-server everything is blank
What can be the configuration issues?

I have added 2 lines in html file since I am using these two external scripts also

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the npx create-react-app command to bootstrap a React application? 
That would save you the stress of having to install all these manually without errors.

Comment: @Idris thank you this is a brilliant idea, so I just create a React app and replace the app.js file inside with my own code right?

Comment: Yes, you can decide to replace the contents of `src/App.jsx` with your code or even further split your code into subcomponents and import where necessary and appropriate. Anyone you decide in your case is fine

Comment: @Idris thank you but after I tried that way it still didn't show up, maybe because this code is using babel preprocessor

Comment: When you see a blank screen in the browser, always check the browser console for errors. That would give you some ideas as to what went wrong.

Comment: Can I see the code? Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: The `npx create-react app` already has all the babel preprocessors and other requirements. The reason is not working must be because you did something wrong and not because of babel. Did you run the command and did it generate a react app folder for you? Did you run `npm start` and did you see the default spinning React Logo?

Comment: Hi @tromgy thanks for the prompt reply, back then I didn't see no error message in the console, maybe I didn't include my css file hence it's not showing

Comment: @Idris thank you, you are a wonderful person, I have included import "./index.css" in my index.js and replace the all the files named index in react-app and now it's working fine

Comment: https://github.com/BunanSia/reactjs-connect-4

Comment: Alright then. That's good to know